# Cómo reducir resultados de una consulta en Sql Server a dos decimales

Tags: sql-server

Tengo un problema al convertir el resultado que devuelve mi consulta pues quiero que solo aparezcan con 2 decimales los resultados en la columna de (nuevo).

ej:

> 34.85893899478         //así muestra el resultado
>
> 34.85                 //así es como quiero que salga

Esta es la  vista donde realizo los cálculos:

```
    create view vista_retenciones
    as
    select l.cod_liquidacion,dc.descripcion,dc.porcentaje,

    CASE dc.descripcion
    when 'RET IT' THEN (dc.porcentaje*l.mas_transporte)/100
    when 'RET IUE' THEN (dc.porcentaje*l.mas_transporte)/100
    else (l.monto*dc.porcentaje)/100

    end  CONVERT(decimal(18, 2)) as nuevo      //aqui es donde no se si estoy aplicando mal lo que quiero hacer 

    from liquidaciones l, descuentos_cooperativa dc
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías convertirlo a DECIMAL:

```
SELECT CAST( 34.85893899478 as DECIMAL(14,2) )
```

Ten en cuenta el tamaño que le colocas.  En este caso coloqué 14.  Si le pones un valor muy pequeño e intentas convertir un número muy grande seguramente te dará error.

Comment: otra opción  seria select convert(DECIMAL(14,2),34.85893899478)